# Should I use both Facebook Relay and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, relay

I am thinking to use Facebook Relay for GraphQL in my project.

I found out that question on Relay is less compare to others approach like “Apollo”, but I still want to have a try on Relay.

As what I understand, Relay can “act” as a state management in React. However, current I had applied my project with Redux.
Is using Relay and Redux together cause duplication of work and confusion?

How should I separate both of them, and take advantage of them together? Should I?

This question might look broad but I can’t find such answer on the Internet.